data augmentation in medical imaging training
I am currently training some data but I noticed the results wasn't very good , so I am trying now to do data augmentation because my data are only 20 patients (mri images of their hearts) . Is it normal to open the new data (after the data augmentation) and the new label not to match the new image?
I tried augmentation on 20 images niifti and the resulted images with the new labels didnt match at all. So now I dont know if I can proceed to the training .
